# Android: No application can perform this action (ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, email, action

first of all I saw the same problem I have, solved here. But even with the answeres there, I didn't solve it. And I couldn't find a place to add comment. Only answer, and being an answer I'm not sure people will be notified with it. that's why I'm creating a new Question. Sorry for that :S

I'm new to Android world, and I'm trying basic stuff. 
This may seem too childish I know, but I can't figure out what the problem is.
I'm trying to open one app to send an email. Wether the native app or not.
I'm using a real device (Sony Ericsson Xperia X10) and I have at least two apps capable or handling email.
I have the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("message/rfc822"); //same with "setType("text/plain")
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.emailAddress)).getText().toString()));
    thisActivity.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose program"));
```

I'm stuck on this and it's making me crazy! I've been searching for a solution, but everybody seems to resolve this matter with the "`setType`" method. This is frustrating because it's such a "small task"... :/

Thank you very much and I'm sorry for "double question".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not use `setData()` here. Use [`EXTRA_EMAIL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL). Or, use `ACTION_SENDTO` instead of `ACTION_SEND`, though then you will need to ensure that you have the `mailto:` scheme in your `Uri`.